# Solve the recurrence for n being a power of k, using the given hint

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

$$T_n = kT_{n/k}+C\log_2{n}
$$

---

C is a positive constant. I think the answer is O(n), but I don't know how to derive with the given hint and without using the master theorem. 
Can anyone help me please, heaps thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yocr6.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

you can try to find the amount of operation (cost) in every lair in the recursive tree:
in first layer its $C\log_2 n$.
in second layer its k times of $C\log_2 n/k$ so its $k C\log_2 (n/k)$.
in third its $k^2 C\log_2 (n/k^2)$.
in the i'sh layer its $k^i C\log_2 (n/k^i)$.
the depth is $\log_k n$ (cause the recursive stops when $n/k^i = 1$), so you need to calculate what is $\sum_{i=0}^{\log_k n} k^i C \log_2 (n/k^i)$